# How do I handle time zones on my Google AppEngine server?

Tags: google-app-engine, timezone

My Google AppEngine app does a url fetch to a remote server to sync RSS feeds from a remote location and shows to users on the client side. These RSS feeds have different time zones. How do I get to manage the different time zones coming from the RSS feeds into my GAE app such that there would be no conflict amongst users viewing the information?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [gae-pytz](http://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/)?  I use it for a different purpose, but it works great for me.